# How can I disable annoying Xperia application on Windows?

Tags: usb, windows, sony-xperia, mtp

This application appears when I connect my Xperia T (CM12) to the PC:

[image: Window]

Usually I just close it, and continue with my work, but even after closing, the application stays open in the taskbar:

[image: In taskbar]

There aren't any settings to disable this type of behaviour.

How can I disable this window (at least from the taskbar), without losing the MTP functionality of the phone?

Comment: I guess this has something to do with [AutoPlay](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows/autoplay-faq#1TC=windows-7). Perhaps try to disable it for this device? (the instruction is on that site)

Comment: Try removing the device from Device and Printers
`Start->Device and Printer ->Right Click on Xperia T`  and `RemoveDevice`

Comment: @AndrewT. that worked for me. Post your solution as an answer so that other people can see it and I can give you bounty. Thanks!

Comment: @sameer the same device I removed reappeared after I plugged the phone again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Xperia Control Panel automatically appears every time you connect the device, it seems a default action is set on Windows [AutoPlay](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows/autoplay-faq#1TC=windows-7).

Usually, Windows will ask the user what to do when a device is connected to the PC (e.g. open folder to view files, take no action, etc.), and the user can set it as default action (which removes this pop-up and directly run the action automatically).

To change/disable this:

1. Open AutoPlay by clicking the **Start** button, and then clicking **Control Panel**. In the search box, type **autoplay**, and then click **AutoPlay**.
2. In the list next to the device or type of media, click the new action you want to use.

For the new action, you can choose **Take no action** so that Windows won't do anything when you connect the device.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definitive answer for you, but I can see one issue you might run into right away. This is a control panel window, so anything you do to stop it from appearing might well affect the whole Control Panel.

Was this something you installed manually or no? If it is, have you tried updating it? If not, I do know that Sony has a standalone PC Companion program, you might try that. The only way I can think to disable this window entirely would be to disable/uninstall your phone in the device manager, but I suspect that's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running Windows 7 on the computer that you had mentioned. If so, type `MSConfig` at the `Start->Run` like this:
[image]

Once it is open, Click on the tab "Startup" which will show all the apps/modules that can load during system start up. Scan through the list carefully and disable (clear the tick/check) the item that you could identify close to the app that causes the issue.

Restart the computer to see this app does not start next time.  However this method will also disable all other features that app provided. You can run the app manually whenever you want to bring back those missing features.

Comment: No, it isn't related to startup (the only thing that is ticked is BitTorrent and Google Update)